# MacBook Air memory corruption solution other than replacing the motherboard

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a MacBook Air 2012 that is randomly restarting when I open a bunch of applications. I ran a memory check (using Rember) and found out that there is a stuck address toward the end of my 8GB of RAM (>7500 to be exact).

As long as I never exceed 7500MB of ram utilization the device works fine.

Is there a way to isolate that portion of the ram and tell the OS never to use it? Like starting an application that grabs that memory region and never gets swapped to SSD?

I'd rather have a 7.5GB working laptop than 8GB randomly restarting one :/